# CSS Select Non Recursive li's Only

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I style only the top level li's from this example list?

```
<ul class='upper'>
  <li class="first">dog</li>
   <li>cat</li>
   <li>bird</li>
   <li>mouse</li>
   <li>
     <ul class="lower">
        <li>chow</li>
        <li>nibz</li>
        <li>seed</li>
        <li>cheese</li>
     </ul>
  </li>


ul.upper > li {
  color:red;
}
```

This styles all li's which I understand because the recursive UL is inside a first level list item. Is there a simple way to style only the top level li's though? Maybe using ":not" in some way?

Edit: I realize you can overwrite the style below it using color:initial or by adding another color(and other ways) but I was wondering if there was a way to ONLY select the top level li's nicely so another style isn't needed.

Comment: just add `li{ color:initial; }` afther that rule

Comment: `:not()` will definitely not help you there as it takes only simple selector without combinators.

Comment: Addressing your edit: No, because your .lower li's are also your .upper li's. Most styles are inherited. You colored the parent, so the child is going to be colored by default.

Comment: @Judd Cobler @your last edit. actually that inheritance is desired. Imagine if you set `font-size` to your body, or `font-family`, and that `style` is not inherited, so you have to manually define it for `each element`,also same story for `color`and other `inheritable props`

Answer (score 3):

So, your `li` are inheriting color from their ancestors, so you need to add `color:initial`, or `color:black` to override that

```css
ul.upper > li {
  color: red;
}
li {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul class='upper'>
  <li class="first">dog</li>
  <li>cat</li>
  <li>bird</li>
  <li>mouse</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="lower">
      <li>chow</li>
      <li>nibz</li>
      <li>seed</li>
      <li>cheese</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Ninja'd before mine, more complete, and cleaner... Guess I'll just delete mine and back this one haha

Answer (score 2):

You want the child combinator, ">"

```
.upper > li
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the deeply nested UL's list-items like this:

```
ul > li {
  color:red;
} 

ul ul > li {
  color: #000;
}
```

So this can work throughout your page to identify any top-level list-items versus second-level list-items, regardless of class name. "ul ul" in CSS means "ul that is inside another ul"

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lyvp2bm/2

(I'm new, how do I add a code snippet to my answer?)